# How to expand until no more braces exist?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

My input is as follows

[image]

I don't want `(t u - b C p)` to exist. How to expand until no more braces exist?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post actual code instead of an image, makes testing a lot easier ;-)

Comment: Are you able to provide code, instead of an image? That way I can easily try this in my instance of Mathematica without having to retype it.

Comment: How so? It shouldn't ever be necessary for questions like this.

Comment: what are the variables here? is `rpt` a variable, or is it `r*p*t`? It is not clear from the picture. `t`,`u`,`b`,`p` all look defined (they're black, not blue), and it is probably frowned upon to use `C` as it is a system symbol.

Comment: Why do the blue and black coloring disagree? I can't reproduce your output by manually typing this myself.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Mathematica 11.0.1, even with verbatim retyping. Waste of time. -1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(From you picture, which isn't entirely useful)

I am going to guess there is some very weird hidden formatting going on that isn't visible to the naked eye, and that it is interpreting `(t u - b C p)` as a single symbol, not as a subtraction within parenthesis to be distributed. My guess it that it was copy and pasted from somewhere and Mathematica didn't interpret that original form properly.

Retype the expression from scratch yourself, and retry it. That is my advice. Here is what happens when I type what you have identically in my session:

[image]

with input form

```
ExpandAll[(((C + b*h)*r*p*t)/Sin[A])*(t*u - b*C*p)]
```

As a side note, I'd avoid using `C` as a symbol, as it is a defined function(ish) in the language. See [this](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) reference page.

Comment: hidden formatting is the culprit.